# using LINQ to separate a list element and inserting the results back to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, cpu-word

I have a list of strings like this("**"Joe**", "**wants**", "**to**", "**thank**", "**you!"**") what I want is to separate "you", "!" and "**"**" and insert them back to that list using LINQ. I know there are many LINQ experts here, which can do it in a minute. What I'm doing is separating a sentence into words:

```
    string sentence = "\"Joe wants to thank you!\"";
    string[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        string word = words[i];
        if (word.EndsWith("."))
        {
            result.Add(word.Substring(0, word.LastIndexOf(".")));
            result.Add(".");
        }
        else if (word.EndsWith("..."))
        {
            result.Add(word.Substring(0, word.LastIndexOf("...")));
            result.Add("...");
        }
        else if (word.EndsWith(","))
        {
            result.Add(word.Substring(0, word.LastIndexOf(",")));
            result.Add(",");
        }
        else if (word.EndsWith("\""))
        {
            result.Add(word.Substring(0, word.LastIndexOf("\"")));
            result.Add("\"");
        }


     }
```

The problem is with sentence that ends with **!"**. **NOTE: words is the array splitted by space.**

Comment: Is there any pattern to those strings? It seems that regular remove will do the work.

Comment: @liran63 ?? how will remove separate a word that is followed by a punctuation, put it back into the list?

Comment: Was that `(""", "Joe", "wants", "to", "thank", "you!", """)` just a `"Joe wants to thank you!"` at some point in your code?

Comment: I guess all he is looking for is adding another else if (word.EndsWith("!")) ... ; Or am I missing anything ?

Comment: Oh sorry I haven't got your question right. I'll try doing that.

Comment: @J0HN this function separeates the "." "," ":" and etc from the normal words

Comment: @fahadash you are right but what about the sentence that ends with ." or !"

Comment: I'm not asking what this function do :) What am I asking is: had this array ever been normal string? If it's so it's much sipler to split by regex in such case.

Comment: @Gohomeurdrunk try it

Comment: you could just `string.replace("!", " !")` first before you split by spaces

Comment: @Sayse I want your mind )) write it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear enough.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are already splitting it by spaces, just [`replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add a space before splitting up

```
sentence = sentence.Replace("!", " !");
```

I don't think you need linq but something kind of elegant for you would be

```
var addMyspace = new List<string>{"!", "...", "\"", ".", ","};

foreach(var s in addMyspace)
{
     sentence = sentence.Replace(s, string.Format(" {0}",s));
}
//split
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're just looking for a regular expression?

```
var sentence = "\"Joe wants to thank you!\"";
var result = Regex.Split(sentence, @"(\.{3}|\W)").Where(w => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w));
```

result is now:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't handle the case of an ellipsis (shown in the sample code in the question). It will split three consecutive periods into three breaks.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thank you. Didn't pay attention to this. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If input array ever been a normal string it's much simpler to split it using regex by `\b`, which means ["word boundary"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
var splitted = Regex.Split(input_string, @"(\.\.\.)|(\W)")
        .Where(chunk => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chunk))
        .Select(chunk => chunk.Trim());
```

Operates equally well with spaces and punctuation, but treats numbers as part of word (e.g. `Joe2` will still remain `Joe2` after splitting).

Also, as `\b` is a zero-length match, speaces are treated as "words", so in order to remove them `Where` is used.

Refer to [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/byy2946e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details

*EDIT*: after fixing flaws pointed out by other guys in the thread this answer become essentially the same as their's. Looks like for this question all correct answers are the same, but every wrong answer is uniquely wrong :)

Comment: splitting by word boundary will not split `!"` into `!` and `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that focuses on using `Regex.Split` more than it does on using Linq (though Linq is still used):

```
string sentence = "\"Joe wants to thank you! comma, ellipsis...exclamation! period.\""; 
string pattern = @"(\.\.\.)|([ ""\.,\\!])";
IEnumerable<string> words = Regex.Split(sentence, pattern)
                                 .Where (x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
foreach (var word in words) { Console.WriteLine(word); }
```

The regex itself splits on any of the characters that you wanted to split on, including the ellipsis (note how this appears in the regex first). The regex uses capturing to return the split char in the output, and Linq is then used to strip out empty items and single spaces.

Output of this one is:

```
"
Joe
wants
to
thank
you
!
comma
,
ellipsis
...
exclamation
!
period
.
"
```

Comment: Very good but what about that sentence in this form: string sentence = "\"Joe wants to thank you!\" Here is another sentence, where we will...get this to work! Right now.";

Comment: @Gohomeurdrunk I modified it to also split on quotes.

Comment: Thank you Yaakov, your code is good but I can accept 1 answer and I'm not quite familiar with Regex and can't modify it how I want. But upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will work for any kind of punctuation you may encounter in the string.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+|(\W)\2*)");

string sentence = "\"Joe wants to thank you! Here is another sentence, where we will...get this to work! Right now.\"";

var words = regex.Matches(sentence).Cast<Match>().Where(m => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value)).Select(m => m.Value);

foreach (var word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

**Output**

```
"
Joe
wants
to
thank
you
!
Here
is
another
sentence
,
where
we
will
...
get
this
to
work
!
Right
now
.
"
```